# How can I put JSON String Data into a Class Object?

Tags: java, class, get, gson

I am trying to obtain data with a http get request in Java and I do actually get the data, however the data is just a String, but I need to be able to use the data, so I thought I'd make a Class that could save the data. However, nothing I tried is working. Not even GSON.

This is what my Main class currenty looking like:
`

```
String data = GetData.getData().replace('"', '\'');
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        
        //ZimmerData orgObject = gson.fromJson(data, ZimmerData.class); 

        //ZimmerData user = gson.fromJson(data, ZimmerData.class);
        System.out.println(data);
```

`

This is how my Data is retrieved:
`

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1520373/feeds.json?results=2");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String output;
        String result = "";
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result += output;
        }
        conn.disconnect();
        return(result);
```

`

And this is how my DataClass is currently looking like (I think I need to fix something there?):
`

```
        private int id;
    private String name;
    private String created_at;
    private String entry_id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
```

`

Can someone please tell me how I could put the data into the class?

I tried to do it without a class, not working either.

I am expecting that all the data (or oh well, most of it but I don't think it matters which specific data I want for one to be able to find a solution) is saved some kind of "storage" where I can for example get the Id of a room...

Comment: What is the json response you get after calling the endpoint? can you please add that to the question

Comment: Can you please also describe what exactly is not working (e.g. values of fields missing, an exception being thrown (in that case please provide the message and stack trace), ...)? Also a few notes: You should probably omit `.replace('"', '\'')`; the JSON specification only allows `"`; there should be no need to transform the JSON in any way. When constructing the `InputStreamReader` explicitly specify the Charset (e.g. `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`) to avoid depending on the system dependent Charset.